# Issue scraping multiple Kubernetes clusters with kube-prometheus-stack

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to scrape multiple clusters into a single Prometheus and I am using a CRD which is composed of multiple components, the component used for monitoring is using **kube-prometheus-stack**. I managed to connect one of the clusters with the following configuration:

```
values: |
    monitoring:
      prometheus:
        prometheusSpec:
          additionalScrapeConfigs: |
            - job_name: "Cluster-1"
              static_configs:
              - targets: ["10.0.0.1:40404"]
```

Essentially, all clusters are using the same CRD with the same configs.

Looking through the logs, I have an error that the cluster that is scraping the configs, and the one that is being scraped, they are using the same naming for labels and containers.

I have been trying to change the naming of the scraper cluster following the default values that **kube-prometheus-stack** has.

I tried to use either `monitoring.nameOverride` either `monitoring.fullnameOverride` but nothing happens. Also I have tried to add those values under `monitoring.prometheus` and agian, nothing happens.

Am I using the wrong approach?